# ReadFile Kernel32 Maximum Buffer Size

Tags: c#, winapi, readfile, kernel32

I am reading directly from a disk using C# and pinvoking the kernel32 ReadFile method.  I notice that with larger reads (currently only reading in single chunks) the buffer size is out of range.

Does anyone know the maximum size of the read buffer here?

If so what is the purpose of limiting the buffer size when I have surplus memory I *want* to read into?  I understand the concepts of buffering and keeping a small memory footprint but why is a small size forced upon us?  Perhaps just an artefact of an old Win32 API?

EDIT:
The error received from `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` is "Value does not fall within the expected range."

The upper limit before I receive this error is 8192 bytes (8KB - hence my confusion).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace DiskRead
{
    class Program
    {
        public const uint GenericRead = 0x80000000;
        public const uint FileShareRead = 1;
        public const uint FileShareWrite = 2;
        public const uint OpenExisting = 3;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
          uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
          uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
           uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"\\.\PhysicalDrive0";

            IntPtr ptr = CreateFile(path, GenericRead, FileShareRead | FileShareWrite, IntPtr.Zero, OpenExisting, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            SafeFileHandle handleValue = new SafeFileHandle(ptr, true);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(handleValue, FileAccess.Read);

            const uint numberOfBytesToRead = 8193;

            uint bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[numberOfBytesToRead];


            if (!ReadFile(handleValue.DangerousGetHandle(), buffer, numberOfBytesToRead, out bytesRead, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post some code here, maybe the problem is in pinvoke?

Comment: I don't think the buffer is limited. I think that if you would just supply some more details (code, error codes) then we could wrap this up.

Comment: I've updated my answer to match. Problem must be elsewhere. 8KB is nothing. I've just done a 1GB buffer no probs! Please show how you call ReadFile.

Comment: Why the hell did you tag this C++? There's nothing C++ about the question.

Comment: @DeadMG In the hope that some seasoned C++ developers might be more accustomed to calling directly into Kernel32 and recognise the issue

Comment: Just to help anyone who sees this - I think when you read from the disk like that, you have to read entire sectors at a time... so buffer must be a multiple of sector size and your offset must be at the start of a sector. Sector size usually is 512 bytes (older HDDs) or 4K bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limit. You are mistaken.

Clearly you are limited by address space and the requirement that the buffer is a contiguous block of virtual memory. On a 32 bit system each process can only address 2GB of virtual memory. What's more you will not be able to allocate a 2GB contiguous block of memory.

But these are general limitations. The `ReadFile` API will happily read into as big a buffer as your can allocate.

You claim to have hit a limit of 8KB but I have just successfully written and read a 1GB file using `WriteFile` and `ReadFile`. Clearly you have some problem but it's just not what you think it is. If you could show the rest of the code, especially that which calls your p/invoke then I'm sure it would become obvious.

---

And now that you have posted your full code we can see what the issue is. You are not reading a file but instead performing read of the physical disk. I see now that's what you meant by "reading directly from a disk" but I think you could have been a bit more specific!

Anyway, I don't know the details of what's happening here, but the issue is clearly not `ReadFile` per se, but that fact that your handle is to the physical disk rather than a file.

The documentation for `CreateFile` states:

> A volume contains one or more mounted file systems. Volume handles can be opened as noncached at the discretion of the particular file system, even when the noncached option is not specified in CreateFile. You should assume that all Microsoft file systems open volume handles as noncached. The restrictions on noncached I/O for files also apply to volumes.
>
> A file system may or may not require buffer alignment even though the data is noncached. However, if the noncached option is specified when opening a volume, buffer alignment is enforced regardless of the file system on the volume. It is recommended on all file systems that you open volume handles as noncached, and follow the noncached I/O restrictions.

I think you should consider asking a new question about how to read from physical disks.

Comment: I have added some more details to the question.  I understand that I am 'clearly' limited by address space - but the errors encountered seemed to indicate there was some kind of acceptable range which was fairly small.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is something else. Once we see more code it will become clear.

Comment: @trickdev I used your code and happily read 1MB. I've no doubt I could read a lot more than that. You still didn't supply a complete example and I had to fill in some blanks. Why can you not supply complete code. Why make it hard for me?

Comment: I was hoping I didn't need to spoon feed the whole thing and it was something you might be able to spot outright, but obviously I was wrong.  All you need to do is ask ;)

Answer (score 1):

### I'm not sure if this helps you, but it may help other readers of this post:

1. When it comes to ReadFile(), it's behavior and success depends heavily on how the file was 
   opened with CreateFile(). Just to give you a point in the right direction think about this; when you call CreateFile() for reading to a buffer, you usually are going to not want the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING unless you are prepared to deal with data alignment and a nice big detour into some of the hardware-specific information, though it probably would just be easier to not.
2. Your code doesn't seem to do this, but it *is* interop, so there could be a garbled value getting though somewhere, and .NET is notorious for molesting(?) memory blocks, so you might want to try allocating the memory via interop to guarentee that the memory block wont move anywhere. Also, i would try minimizing interop as much as possible, it seems to be somewhat unreliable when it is needed most. Instead, you might consider writing a DLL that will play *nicer* with your code and interop it instead.. I have done this in many cases and it works pretty well and adds the bonus of not having to write the same code over, just reuse it in as many programs as you like... As for the root cause of your problem, I havent been able to duplicate it myself, the largest file Ive tried is about 800MB and it opened,read,closed ok... can you make available the source so it can be tested by others (or a very verbose built executable) to see if others have the same problems with it?   Anyways hope this helped someone.

### Resources

- [CreateFile() ReadFile() from MSDN 2011 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
  (paragraphs 9 and 13 under the Remarks section)
- [File Buffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950.aspx)
  Restrictions of buffer sizes and sector-alignment
  Further note recommends using VirtualAlloc() to get an aligned chunk of memory

Comment: Welcome to SO, @osirisgothra. I edited your post (the edit is still pending). Please have a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the max size of the buffer to read into, however the reason for a size of the buffer at all, is so that internally in the function a check can be made so no data is written past the end of the buffer.  If the function had no notion of the size of the input buffer, it could write past the end of the buffer, causing a **buffer overflow**.  That would be a serious security flaw.

Comment: Thanks Tony, a point well raised.  As I think you have noticed, not quite what I was getting at but entirely my fault for the wording of the question.

Comment: @trickdev I know this isn't really what you're looking for, but I thought I'd mention it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

While `ReadFile` is running, the kernel must lock the buffer. It must do so, or evil things could happen (a page could not be present when it tries to copy data, or worse... DMA into it).

Every application has limitations on its working set, which you can also [configure programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you (or the kernel on your behalf) try to lock more memory than allowed by your working set limits, this fails. You can't lock more than your minimum working set size, which defaults to a rather small value (IIRC something like 16MB).

Note that the "maximum working set size" is not how much memory your application is allowed to use (that would be tragic). It's rather a figure of when a page belonging to your process is considered as "might be paged out in case someone else wants memory".

The intent behind all this is to ensure that the system keeps working with many programs running concurrently, using unknown amounts of memory.

Comment: There's nothing that says that ReadFile must lock the entire buffer in one go. So whilst what you say may be correct (I don't know if it is), it is orthogonal to ReadFile's implementation.